# Loading DEM with unkown CRS using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, dem

I am trying to load a DEM (img file + prj file) into QGIS 3.12.1 and use it as a layer over OpenStreetMap. However, I can't seem to get the CRS right, the OTF-conversion does not show the layer on the map.

I am using EPSG:3857 as project default and the read CRS from the prj file with OTF CRS conversion enabled:

```
PROJCS[
    "Transverse_Mercator",
    GEOGCS["GCS_Geographic Coordinate System",DATUM["D_MGI",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528131060786]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",10.33333333333333],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",-5000000],
    UNIT["Meter",1]
]
```

How can I transform this CRS to EPSG:3857?

Here are the files I am trying to load: https://vogis.cnv.at/geodaten/?service=files&t=418171be46e40175bfe171edfc4097dd&path=%2FGelaendemodelle%2FHoehenmodelle%2FVlbg_Umgebung

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like MGI / Austria GK West (EPSG:31254) or MGI / Austria GK M28 (EPSG:31257), no other *tmerc* projection has *lon_0* at 10.333333 in proj EPSG file. From the epsg file (/usr/share/proj/epsg on Linux):

```
...
# MGI (Ferro) / Austria GK West Zone
<31251> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=28 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=682,-203,480,0,0,0,0 +pm=ferro +units=m +no_defs  <>
...
# MGI / Austria GK M28
<31257> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=10.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=150000 +y_0=-5000000 +datum=hermannskogel +units=m +no_defs  <>
...
```

I downloaded your smaller file gtxxxx_25m and opened in QGIS and changed the unknown projection to EPSG:31254 and added to OSM standard layer. Here is the result, it looks good.

[image]